# TypeAhead Feature TextBox Control Windows C#

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I am using typeahead feature of TextBox .. all I want is that the Typeahead should show all the Items available in AutoCompleteStringCollection.

Currently its suggesting me those string whcih starts with the characters that I type.
What I need is the characters that I type can exist anywhere in the string not only at beginning.

On TextChange Event
What I am doing to get this is making a temp AutoCompleteStringCollection and associating it with the textBox.

Now all I need to do is just display that every time.
any Ideas?

Comment: Umm, more information please? What have you tried? What exactly do you want it to do? What is it doing right now?

Answer (score 0):

The Winform controls with AutoComplete support are using IE's AutoComplete APIs, which does not support ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING until Windows Vista. Since WinForm needs to support earlier systems, ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING is not supported in .Net.

If you want to use this feature when it is available, you can [skip Windows Form's AutoComplete support and call the API directly](http://jiangsheng.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1BE894DEAF296E0A!732.entry).